# Controle de Acesso HTTP (CORS) para múltiplos domínios

Tags: html, http-request, mod-rewrite, cors

Como liberar Controle de Acesso HTTP (CORS) de imagens usando XMLHttpRequest para todos os domínios abaixo no .htaccess e não usando permissão global com "*":

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.osite.com.br,
https://osite.com.br, http://osite.com.br, https://subdomain.osite.com.br,
http://www.subdomain.osite.com.br
```

Mesmo colocando assim, não funcionou, está dando erro por causa do acesso quando entro no domínio: **http://www.osite.com.br/imagem.jpg** não funciona, quando entro **http://osite.com.br/imagem.jpg** funciona:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(osite.com.br|subdomain.osite.com.br|)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
```

**Obs:** o site e a imagem são fictício, apenas para representar o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Para que o parâmetro `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` funcione desta forma você precisa usar o parâmetro `replace=false`, para que não haja sobreposição de cabeçalhos... assim:

```
header ("access-control-allow-origin: endereço1");
header ("access-control-allow-origin: endereço2", false);
header ("access-control-allow-origin: endereço3", false);
header ("access-control-allow-origin: endereço4", false);
```